# Effect of potential difference on capacitance

Tags: electricity, capacitance

I've read multiple threads here discussing the relation between capacitance and potential difference and they have begun to confuse me. I have a homework question about which of the following will increase the capacitance of a parallel plate capacitor. I have settled on "an increase in the plate area and a decrease in the plate separation" because this seemed like the obvious answer. However, I am bothered by the choice "a decrease in the potential difference between the plates." Examining the formula C=Q/delta V, I concluded that delta V and C are inversely proportional and thus a decrease in delta V would lead to a smaller number in the denominator and an increase in C. What am I missing here? Thanks!

In reply to below:

@Farcher Basically, the question asked "which of the following will increase the capacitance of a parallel plate capacitor?" I thought the most obvious answer would be "an increase in the plate area and a decrease in the plate separation," but I also saw "a decrease in the potential difference between the plates" as viable due to the equation C=Q/delta V. However, after viewing various pdf's online and threads on here, some people only mention the plate separation and plate area as affecting the capacitance. I would really appreciate if someone cleared this business up by telling me if potential difference can in fact affect capacitance.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.  If you have two capacitors storing the same charge then the capacitor with the smaller potential difference across its plates will have the larger capacitance.

Comment: @Farcher Thanks for replying. I added some more information above that hopefully makes my question more clear.

Comment: You are assuming a vacuum between the plates?

Comment: Yes, I believe so

Comment: A way that the capacitance can change with the applied voltage is if the dielectric constant is actually a function of electric field strength.  Such materials exist, for example http://electrons.wikidot.com/direction-electric-field-dependence-of-dielectric-constant but I think the simple answer is that the capacitance of a capacitor does not depend on the potential difference across the plates.

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate? More specifically, why doesn't the equation C=Q/delta V dictate an indirect relationship between capacitance and potential difference?

Comment: The definition of capacitance is $C=\dfrac QV$ and for a parallel plate capacitor $C= \dfrac{\epsilon_oA}{d}$.

Comment: So V does not affect capacitance because this scenario is a parallel plate capacitor?